# How to integrate the network for getting iAd in the iphone?

Tags: iphone

I Have the code to get an iAd in the current application for the iphone. but i want to connect to the network in order to display the real adds. now iam able to display a black template. please help me reg. this and suggest how i have to connect to the network for the iAd Display.

Answer (score 1):

You need to accept the iAd contract and register your app to use iAd in iTunes Connect. You will then see test ads while your app is in development and your customers will get real ads if they are available in the customer's region once your app is shipped.